# Question mark on svn timeline?

Tags: svn

It's a strange question.
The svn server is Ubuntu 9.04.
And the client is Versions 1.07 on mac os x.
Commit and Checkout is work well.
But the comment can't view.So I could't know who modified the svn.
And in the versions timeline ,the all logs is question mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.Modify the conf/svnserve.conf file,change the value of "anon-access" to "none"